# How can I edit the name provided in the billing block for an event registration?

Tags: civicontribute, billingblock

In CiviCRM 4.6.18 I have enabled the billing block for pay later registrations for an event. I've noticed that a users are registering and using the billing block, and entering their names incorrectly (most commonly entering a name all in lower case).

I can subsequently edit the contact record to correct the capitalisation (or other issue) with the contact's name, but the name in the billing address does not reflect these edits, and neither can I find any way to edit this billing name through the UI - editing the billing address does not provide access to the name fields.

Am I missing something here?

This billing block seems to highly inflexible. Perhaps its better to not use it at all, and have a second profile instead that I can better control.

Answer (score 2):

Graham,

You will have the issue with first and last name no matter where users enter the information. The name is entered as the contact name and the billing fields are just pulling the data for the billing address.  I would like at the Civi Normalize Extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/normalise-data-entered-firstname-last-name) to help you with this.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Thanks Steve. I'm aware of this extension, but haven't implemented it thus far as (the last time I checked at least) it doesn't appear to be compatible with 4.6.x.  I accept that if implemented it would reduce the need to correct billing names, but still the issue remains of there being no apparent means of editing name fields in the billing block, which feels to me like a significant oversight.

Comment: Also, I've not marked this answer as accepted because it doesn't answer the question as stated - that being "How can I edit the name provided in the billing block for an event registration?".

Comment: Hi Graham,

When the billing address is filled out from an online form, it creates a record in the address table that is not linked to a contact id - what is included is a name that concatenates whatever values are entered in first, middle and last name fields of the billing block, but I can't for the life of me find which table(s) link the information to the contact record of the participant/contributor - so I'd be interested to know where that information is stored myself, but my guess is that there is no option to update this name through the UI and it may be considered a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Graham, just found out that editing billing address information is possible as with any other address information as of 4.7.9 (possibly earlier). Yay!